# Can 'Could' be used instead of May/MIght?

Tags: could

Can I use Could instead of May/Might.

e.g. That could be the reason.

Is this sentence correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Could" is a clear way of expressing possibility, just like "might" in many sentences. However, it can also refer to capability, which might not make as much sense in some cases.

In the sentence in the question, "could" does mean about the same thing as "might". It says "it's possible but there is not certainty", which is what "might" also says.